# Parsing XML data into pandas multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas, xml.etree

I want to parse data from an XML file into an multiindex pandas dataframe. My XML File looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book name="Documents/Books/German">
      <author>Kerstin Gier</author>
      <title>Rubinrot</title>
   </book>
   <book name="Documents/Articles/English">
      <author>Kim Ralls</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   </book>
   <book name="Documents/Books/English">
      <author>Eva Corets</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
   </book>
   <book name="Documents/Books/English">
      <author>Karl Parker</author>
      <title>Worldeater</title>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

The goal is to store the data from all book tags into an multiindex pandas dataframe which should look like follows:

```
                              author        title   
Documents  Books     German   Kerstin Gier  Rubinrot        
                     English  Eva Corets    Maeve Ascendant
                              Karl Parker   Worldeater
           Articles  German   Null          Null
                     English  Kim Ralls     Midnight Rain
```

The index of the multiindex dataframe should be the paths which the attribute "name" contains. I don't want to hardcode any paths because my real world example has many different paths and the multiindex dataframe will have 5-6 dimensions.

My approach so far:
I started to create a single index dataframe which looks like so

```
path                        author        title 
Documents/Books/German      Kerstin Gier  Rubinrot
Documents/Articles/English  Kim Ralls     Midnight Rain
Documents/Books/English     Eva Corets    Maeve Ascendant
Documents/Books/English     Karl Parker   Worldeater
```

The question is: how can I convert the dataframe into a multiindex dataframe with the path structure as indexes? The problem I see is to change the indexes without loosing the binding to the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an XML file to nice pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: No I need an solution that generates an multiindex dataframe. That's (as far as I noticed) more complicated. Thanks for the advise though. It's a good backup solution.

Comment: Is it not an option to parse it this way, then create the multiindex after the fact?

Comment: This might be an option. I edited my question. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Answered based on edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on you original question and edits, here's the follow up solution. Using the parsing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe), and the ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns):

We take the existing path column, split it on `/` and convert it to a list, then use those list values to create new columns.

Then we use those columns as the new index.

```
df

    path                    author          title
0   Documents/Books/German  Kerstin_Gier    Rubinrot
1   Documents/Articles/English  Kim_Ralls   Midnight_Rain
2   Documents/Books/English Eva_Corets  Maeve_Ascendant
3   Documents/Books/English Karl_Parker Worldeater

df[['cat','type','lang']]=pd.DataFrame(df['path'].str.split('/').values.tolist(), index=df.index)

df

    path                    author          title       cat         type    lang
0   Documents/Books/German  Kerstin_Gier    Rubinrot    Documents   Books   German
1   Documents/Articles/English  Kim_Ralls   Midnight_Rain   Documents   Articles    English
2   Documents/Books/English Eva_Corets  Maeve_Ascendant Documents   Books   English
3   Documents/Books/English Karl_Parker Worldeater  Documents   Books   English

df.set_index(['cat','type','lang'])

                                path                    author          title
cat         type        lang            
Documents   Books       German  Documents/Books/German  Kerstin_Gier    Rubinrot
            Articles    English Documents/Articles/English  Kim_Ralls   Midnight_Rain
            Books       English Documents/Books/English Eva_Corets  Maeve_Ascendant
                        English     Documents/Books/English Karl_Parker Worldeater
```

From there, obviously you can `drop` the path if desired

Comment: No problem, happy to help out!

Comment: @G.Anderson - can you explain why when `cat` was a column, it had 4 entries - all `Documents`; once `set_index` made it an index, it has only one, with the other three left blank. Similarly for the `type` column, which - as an index - has one blank.

Comment: @JackFleeting that's the default display for a multi index in pandas. Because the other values are just repeats of the initial value, it doesn't display them

Comment: @JackFleeting [this behavior can be changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211350/showing-all-index-values-when-using-multiindexing-in-pandas)

Comment: @G.Anderson - makes sense, but in `lang` as a column, `English` is repeated 3 times in succession; in `type`, `Books` is repeated once, though not in succession.

Comment: @JackFleeting this, honestly, just _is_ how it displays. The default for a single index (or, in this case, the last layer of a multiindex) is to show all values. If you check the values in the 2nd and 3rd index, you see that they're repeated because they're all different combinations. `[(Books, German),(Articles, English),(Books, English),(Books, English)]`

Comment: (except the last, where `books` isn't repeated)