# Multiindex with values in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["1", "1", "1", "2", "3"],
                   "value" : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
                   "a" : [1,2,3,4,5]})
df.set_index(["ID", "value"], inplace=True)
```

[image]

And what can I do so as to have multiindex "ID" and "value" like below:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing all index values when using multiIndexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211350/showing-all-index-values-when-using-multiindexing-in-pandas)

Answer (score -1):

Try resetting index

`df.reset_index(col_fill=['values', 'ID'])`

it will create one more column which you can `drop` or `pop` from DataFrame.

The Final frame will be

```
ID  value  a
 1     10  1
 1     11  2
 1     12  3
 2     13  4
 3     14  5
```